# How to get information from all collection, but get only item of array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB with NodeJS, and I keep my data in a collection called "posts", in this way

```
     {
                "_id": "5ca0ff61f247dc29b8331af9",
                "tipo": "First Mongo Post",
                "user": {
                    "_id": "5ca01d2c56a2d9165c848f4f",
                    "nombre": "User1",
                    "email": "luis@gmail.com",
                    "permission": "Administrador",
                    "__v": 0
                },
                "rates": [
                    {
                        "user": "5ca01d2c56a2d9165c848f4f",
                        "votation": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "user": "5ca021b03904f70cf823b6e6",
                        "votation": -1
                    }
                ],
                "__v": 0
      }
```

I would like to think that the way that I save my data its correctly, whatever, I want to get all the information from my collection called "posts", but the array called **rates**, I only want to get the object that the user its the same like the user that make the call to the get method.

For example, If I call my **get** method, and I send the user ID (5ca01d2c56a2d9165c848f4f), I want to return **all** posts collection but in the the rates array of each one I only want to have the object that has the same ID compared by the ID that I sent in the **get** method, for example:

```
 {
            "_id": "5ca0ff61f247dc29b8331af9",
            "tipo": "First Mongo Post",
            "user": {
                "_id": "5ca01d2c56a2d9165c848f4f",
                "nombre": "User1",
                "email": "luis@gmail.com",
                "permission": "Administrador",
                "__v": 0
            },
            "rates": [
                {
                    "user": "5ca01d2c56a2d9165c848f4f",
                    "votation": 1
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
}
```

To be honest, I don't know how can I do it, so i hope that you can help me or explain me how can I do it, please.

Regards, I'm new using this technologies

Answer (score 0):

You can store Rate and Post objects separately, so you can create a new collection called **rates** to keep Rates separately from Posts collection. In the Rate collection you can store the postId, userId and votation value

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const RateSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userId: {
    type: String
  },
  postId: {
    type: String
  },
  votation: {
    type: Number,
  }
);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Rate', RateSchema);
```

After that you can create a function to get the rates that is related to userId and postId like

```
const Rate = require('../models/Rate');
function getRatesByUserIdandPostId(userId, postId) {
   return Rate.find({userId, postId});
};
```

This way you don't need to search in a for loop for which rate is relate to that user, function will do it for you. Also it is faster because you don't get all the rates that is related to one specific post.